# How to close existing SSL Tunnels via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssl, vpn, sonicwall

I want to kill the RDP app, VPN Client app and all its existing tunnels using powershell. The commands below works to kill the apps:

```
Stop-Process -name mstsc -F
Stop-Process -name SWGVC -F
```

However, the current tunnel still stays so I can keep pinging any laptop using our office network although VPN is closed.

When I searched how to close the existing VPN tunnels via PowerShell, I see I can find the VPN connections using `get-vpnconnection` and then do `Disconnect-VpnUser` but `get-vpnconnection` returns no data at all. When I go to "Network and Internet" from Settings and check if there is any VPN added, none.

How can I be sure the existing SSL tunnels are closed when the VPN app is killed using powershell?
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to check the VPN adapters connections

[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | select Name,Description,Operationalstatus

Comment: Thanks Paul, it seems like Ethernet 3 runs the VPN but how can I proceed then to take it down?

Comment: Hi Eray, Could you try this command to disable the the VPN adapter and check,

Get-NetAdapter "Ethernet 3" | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false -PassThru 


   If you want re-enable it try the below command,
Get-NetAdapter "Ethernet 3" | Enable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false -PassThru